# Django .save() Reverts

Tags: python, mysql, django, save

I have an InteferField set in models called the status.  I have a method that is two switch the value of two rows statuses.

```
Row one -> status = 1
Row two -> status = 2
```

Now, I figure, if I switch row one's status to some unattainable reach (99) I could use that as the middle man to switch row two and then switch row one.

```
Get status = 1 -> Row one
Get status = 2 -> Row two
Set Row one -> status = 99
Save Row one
Set Row two -> status = 1
Save Row two
Get status = 99 -> Row one
Set Row one -> status = 2
Save Row one
```

The strange thing is, the data reverts.  If I just change the status of Row one to 99, it will change to 99 and then a moment later, back to its original value.  We're not sure why this is happening, but it turns out nothing is come from this at all.

```
original = 1
swap = 2

originalCase = Case.objects.get(queue_num = original)
#swapCase = Case.objects.get(queue_num = swap)
originalCase.queue_num = 99
originalCase.save()
#swapCase.queue_num = original
#swapCase.save()
#originalCase = Case.objects.get(queue_num = 99)
#originalCase.queue_num = swap
#originalCase.save()
return HttpResponse(Case.objects.filter(queue_num__gt=0).order_by('queue_num'))
```

Is it because we're querying to fast and it's not updating in time for the next update? Or is there a flaw in my logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... Shouldn't the following:

```
originalCase = Case.objects.get(queue_num = swap)
```

Be this:

```
originalCase = Case.objects.get(queue_num = 99)
```

If you copy and pasted that code as is, that's your problem. You're essentially fetching the one you just changed and changing it back.

**UPDATE:**

Simplifying your code may help ferret out the problem, as well. You don't technically need a swap placeholder. Since the query hits the database only once when initially fetching all the objects, you could do something like the following:

```
cases = Case.objects.all()
for case in cases:
    if case.queue_num == original:
        case.queue_num = swap
    elif case.queue_num == swap:
        case.queue_num = original

    case.save()
```

Or if you want to keep the same idea, you could even do the following (which might actually be simpler):

```
Case.objects.filter(queue_num=original).update(queue_num=99)
Case.objects.filter(queue_num=swap).update(queue_num=original)
Case.objects.filter(queue_num=99).update(queue_num=swap)
```

Comment: Woops, sorry, that is the code we have.  But I also ran just the editted code, and it still reverts.

Comment: I think your code needs more context. Based on what you've posted, it should not be "reverting" any more.

Comment: Exactly why we are confused.  We are only running that single function.  That is the full function there.  We do the request, and thats it.  The tab is left open.  But after the HttpResponse, nothing should be happening.

Comment: We cleared out the problem.  It was actually coming down to a problem with the urls.py.  The root was also calling another function that we weren't meaning to call.  We had (r'^$','index') above this function thus calling a resetting method.  Thanks for the help and for the advised simpler code.

Answer (score 0):

line 2,3,4 from the bottom have no effect:

```
originalCase = Case.objects.get(queue_num = swap)
originalCase.queue_num = swap
originalCase.save()
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistype.  It was originally queue_num = 99, BUT even when I run the editted code, it still reverts.